# Use of uninitialised value of size 8 using rewind or fgets

Tags: c

I am new to C. Having few problems with the way my file is being read. Using valgrind, I have "use of uninitialised value of size 8" and conditional jumps in while-loop. Please help me understand where I am going wrong. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 30
#define LINESIZE 128
int main()
{
    char fileName[30];
    char courseName[30];
    printf("Please enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    //printf("%s is the fileName", fileName);

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen(fileName,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exsists\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int lines;
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch=='\n')
            lines++;
    }
    //fclose(fp);
    int i=0;
    char courses[lines][30];


  rewind(fp);
    while (fgets( courses[i], MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
    {
        //printf("At line %d we have %s", i, courses[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Errors that I get

```
==1057== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1057==    at 0x108A81: main (course_graph.c:33)
==1057== 
==1057== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1057==    at 0x4EC43B0: rewind (rewind.c:32)
==1057==    by 0x522D8BF: ???
==1057==    by 0x4E5DB96: (below main) (libc-start.c:310)
==1057== 
==1057== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1057==    at 0x4EC441F: rewind (rewind.c:35)
==1057==    by 0x1FFEFFFF5F: ???
==1057==    by 0x4E5DB96: (below main) (libc-start.c:310)
```

Comment: `lines++;` Lines is _undefined_ as you never give it an initial value. You need: `int lines = 0;`

Comment: You forgot to include <stdio.h>. `#include`s are not optional, your compiler should at least have warned you. Enable warnings for your compiler and treat warnings as errors

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyMopp. That was the problem. jabberwocky, I have the include statement. It was the lines++; that fixed it.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  You can not reliably detect `EOF` if you stuff it into a `char` value.